# Django Singularize Strings

Tags: python, django

Is there an easy way to singularize plural strings in Django? It seems like there must be, since Django itself clearly requires going back and forth between singular and plural for model and database conventions. I need to accomplish something similar, where I'm given a pluralized resource name known only at runtime and I need to dynamically access that class version of that using getattr().

Comment: Can you give us more details?

Comment: You can always create your own filter. You could refer to this: https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/template/defaultfilters.py#L896

Comment: As long as you *know* its been pluralised (in which case you possibly have a reference to the original somewhere already) you can reverse the logic to do so... If not then, then not really... (not reliably anyway)

Comment: Why would Django require going back and forth? Just store the singular and display the plural when needed.